# How to convert a ByteString to String in yml file. GCP secret manager, spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-jpa, yaml

I followed the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/current/reference/html/secretmanager.html#_secret_manager_property_source and the **bootstrap.yml** file looks like this:

```
spring:
   clouds:
     gcp:
       secret manager:
         enabled: true
         secret-name-prefix: "sm://"
         project-id: my-project-id
   data source:
     username: "${sm://datasource-username}"
     password: test
```

and the application.yml file looks like this:

```
spring:
   clouds:
     gcp:
       projectId: my-project-id
       SQL:
         instance-connection-name: "my-instance"
         databaseName: testDatabase
```

and I get this error:

```
Property: spring.datasource.username\n Value: ${sm://datasource-username}\n Origin: class path resource [bootstrap.yml] - 9:15\n

Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString] to type [java.lang.String]\n\nAction:\n\nUpdate your application's configuration\n"}
```

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong :(
I think I need a converter(.toStringUtf8()) in bootstrap.yml, but I don't no how to implement a converter in yml file. Any idea is helpful, thanks a lot

Comment: please share your yml file

Comment: There is far too little information here. Why is it read using protobuf in the first place? Why is this even happening and it looks like you are working around Spring/Spring Boot instead of using it properly.

Comment: I want to get the username and password from the secret manager on google cloud, I followed this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/current/reference/html/secretmanager.html, and I got the above error.

I want to mention that initially I tried only for the username, as you can see in the code above.

I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong to get this error

Comment: You do have the proper dependencies and versions?

Comment: I think so, I have this dependency     implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:1.2.8.RELEASE")
do I have to have another dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this dependency and it worked:

```
implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:3.2.1")
```